# Why does `full_join` increase the numbers of rows when there are duplicates?

Tags: r, dplyr

I noticed `full_join` and been doubling rows when I am matching on rows with duplicates id's. Is there a way I can include the unique rows from two datasets without duplicating data? I could imagine making another unique identifier.

```r
library(dplyr)

## two row output as expected
x <- tibble(id = c(1,2))
full_join(x, x, by="id")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>      id
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2


## 1's double
y <- tibble(id = c(1,1,2))
full_join(y, y, by="id")
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>      id
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
#> 2     1
#> 3     1
#> 4     1
#> 5     2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That's how a `full_join` works? Not being sarcastic but that's what I would expect from a full join. My suggestion is to deduplicate both datasets before joining.

Comment: Check out this SQL answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27458534

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a `union` or `bind_rows` operation rather than a `join`? I'm guessing a bit here but I get the impression you want to stack your data rather than adding columns from one dataset to the other.

Comment: quick solution. Add `%>% unique()` at the end of the `full_join`. At least you'll have unique values.

Comment: The key issue here is that dplyr does not and should not assume that these are duplicates. The question is also not really clear. Are you querying how `full_join` works or are you simply asking how to remove duplicates from a data frame? In that case just use `distinct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to your question has already been given in the comments. But I will try to illustrate the problem in a little more detail. Maybe it helps :)

First of all: a join tries to match each id-element of dataframe A to a corresponding id-element of dataframe B. If there are duplicate ids in A or B, the join will find produce multiple matches. This is not a special case of a full join.

Here are a few examples (the most common joins I think). I have added an extra column so you can see how the values are joined.

```
x <- dplyr::tibble(id=c(1,1,2,3,4),
                   val1=c(1,2,3,4,5))
y <- dplyr::tibble(id=c(1,1,3),
                   val2=c("a","b","c"))
```

full join

```
dplyr::full_join(x,y,by="id")

# A tibble: 7 x 3
     id  val1 val2 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     1 a    
2     1     1 b    
3     1     2 a    
4     1     2 b    
5     2     3 NA   
6     3     4 c    
7     4     5 NA
```

left join

```
dplyr::left_join(x,y,by="id")

# A tibble: 7 x 3
     id  val1 val2 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     1 a    
2     1     1 b    
3     1     2 a    
4     1     2 b    
5     2     3 NA   
6     3     4 c    
7     4     5 NA
```

right join

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     id  val1 val2 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     1 a    
2     1     2 a    
3     1     1 b    
4     1     2 b    
5     3     4 c
```

anti join

```
dplyr::anti_join(x,y,by="id")

    id  val1
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     3
2     4     5
```